# index.sublime-project and index.sublime-workspace files

Tags: sublimetext3

I have a directory named project, and I navigated to Project > Add Folder to Project... in order to see the directory tree in my left sidebar. I noticed that doing this creates a file called index.sublime-project with the following content:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ]
}
```

I also noticed that there is another file in my directory called index.sublime-workspace, although this one does not appear in the tree view on the left sidebar of Sublime. It is only visible through windows explorer when I navigated to the Project directory.

What is the purpose of these files? Can I prevent them from being created every time I add folder to project?

Answer (score 0):

Adding directories to the window using `Project > Add Folder to Project` is indeed one of the ways to open a folder (the others being to drag and drop a folder onto the window and `File > Open Folder`).

However, doing so do not create those files. To create them, you would need to use the `Project > Save Project` menu item. So you may have accidentally done that without realizing it. In theory a plugin could also create those files for you, though that seems unlikely (anything is possible though).

In any case, assuming you don't want them it's entirely safe to remove them.

A `sublime-project` file is a file that allows you to open folders in the side bar and then do things like apply settings that apply only to files in that window, alter what files and folders appear, and so on.

A `sublime-workspace` file is a localized session information for a particular window. Usually, they associated with a `sublime-project` file but they don't have to be. They store the state of the window, open files, etc so that you can close a window and then recall it later with the same state.